# How do I earn the Batman hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

[image: Coz I want to be Batman]

I recently saw that the [User Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) had a Batman hat awarded to it.
Can a normal user be awarded a Batman hat? If so, how?

Comment: https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/im-batman

Comment: @Vaulstein: Maybe because it's very easy to find the answer...

Comment: @KevinGuan: Even if I google how to get the batman hat on stackoverflow, the first result is my question and the next few results are of earlier winter bashes 2013,2014. No, result for 2015.

Comment: How the devil is this "Primarily opinion based"? LOL What is wrong with you close voters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the hat's description](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/im-batman) states, you need to edit a closed question that you did not participate in closing (i.e. you didn't cast a close vote or handle this question in one of the review queues).

Editing a closed questions automatically nominates it for reopening (in the Reopen Votes review queue). If the question actually gets reopened, you'll get the hat.

Comment: What if, instead, in your childhood you fall into a bat infested cave getting shocked for life and later have your father killed by a criminal that will develop a laughing grin and weird sense of humor? Would that be enough?

Comment: @FrancescoMM Not enough. *Both* parents!

Comment: LOL, @BilltheLizard you are right! Then I better try to edit a closed question. Both parents might be too much for me (although you'd also get a great car in the deal).